# How to create table in Visual Studio 2015 without SQL Server, is it possible?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015

How to create table in Visual Studio 2015 without SQL Server, is it possible? I haven't installed any SQL Server software externally in my system.

Comment: What kind of a table do you mean? A table in a sql database? Or a table in html, xaml, ... ?

Comment: Of course - you can create an Access table, or a SQLite table, or whatever you want from Visual Studio. But if you **don't have ANY** version of SQL Server installed, you **CANNOT** create a SQL Server based database and table. Period.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can for example get SQLite from Nuget and use it instead. ie:

```
string dataFile = @"d:\temp\KisiLinkleri.db";
SQLiteConnection conn;

void Main()
{
    conn =  new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source="+dataFile);
    CreateTable( dataFile );
    CreateData();

     Kisi kisi = FindKisi(214);

   Console.WriteLine( kisi.KayitOlLink );

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
      SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from Kisiler",conn);
      conn.Open();
      tbl.Load( cmd.ExecuteReader());
      conn.Close();


    tbl.Dump();
}


private void CreateData()
{
    SQLiteCommand sql = new SQLiteCommand(
     @"INSERT INTO Kisiler 
     (Id,KayitOlLink) 
     VALUES 
     (@id, @kayitOlLink )", conn);

    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 0);
    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kayitOlLink", "");

    conn.Open();
    SQLiteTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
      sql.Parameters["@Id"].Value = null;
      sql.Parameters["@kayitOlLink"].Value = string.Format("Kayit Ol Link #{0}", i+1);
      sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }    
    transaction.Commit();
    conn.Close();
}

private Kisi FindKisi(int id)
{
    Kisi k = new Kisi();
    conn.Open();
    SQLiteCommand sql = new SQLiteCommand( 
    @"select * from  Kisiler where Id = @id", conn);

    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    SQLiteDataReader rdr = sql.ExecuteReader();
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
        rdr.Read();
        k = new Kisi { 
            Id=Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Id"]), 
            KayitOlLink=(string)rdr["KayitOlLink"] };
    }
    conn.Close();
  return k;
}

private void CreateTable(string dataFile)
{
  if ( File.Exists( dataFile ) )
  {
    File.Delete( dataFile );
  }

    conn.Open();
    string createTable =  @"CREATE TABLE [Kisiler] (
    [Id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    [KayitOlLink] [varchar](200))"; 

    new SQLiteCommand(createTable, conn).ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    conn.Close();
}

private void SaveKisi(Kisi kisi)
{
    conn.Open();
    SQLiteCommand sql = new SQLiteCommand(
     @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Kisiler 
     (KayitOlLink) 
     VALUES 
     (@kayitOlLink )", conn);

    sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kayitOlLink", kisi.KayitOlLink);
    sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}

public class Kisi
{ 
  public int? Id { get; set; }
  public string KayitOlLink { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local database using SQL Express Local Database which is included in (at least most versions) VS2015. Follow this [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx)